# Do i have to dismiss a viewcontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

When working in Ios and multiple view controllers, when presenting modally, I have the option of dismissing the view that was just loaded by using the dismiss() function. However, why do I have to dismiss the view? Cant I just performsegue() back to the previous view and get the same result? Is it more resource intinsive to not dismiss and just performsegue() another view controller.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Also if someone would be kind enough to inform me why i keep getting down voted for this question that would be great

Comment: I know nothing about your question, but as to your comment, you may want to check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

in a segue you create a new object of the desired view.so to reverse back you can use navgations.if you create a new segue to the previous view then it will create a new object of the previous view which is not very memory saving and doesn't really takes you to previous view but to a new copy of previous view.Hope it helps..